# How can I drag files from a Web View to the desktop?

Tags: cocoa, webview, draggable, attachment, desktop

I am not sure if the Mail application uses a Webview to display it's content, but if it does I am curious how in xCode (Swift) you can display a file in a WebView and let the user be able to drag a file out on to the Desktop. Just as you would drag an attachment out of a Mail message.

Comment: No, Mail doesn't use a WebView to display its content. An attachment file icon displayed in a message, is a subview of the message window's main view. Dragging and dropping between such views is straightforward. A WebView is quite different in that it displays HTML content within a single view, so there's no way (via Cocoa) to drag things out of it. If you have control of the web content, you may be able to use Javascript to make something draggable, but then you'd also need to create some interface with the WebView to handle it. I don't think there's a simple, straightforward way to do this.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the content of Mail is done through Rich Text Format rather then HTML within a WebView?

Comment: Yes, that's how it appears to me (though I can't be absolutely certain). Even if it is a WebView, then Mail must be pre-processing the HTML content, adding data detectors, and controlling the download of remote content. So, an attachment is treated as a separate object that can be opened, dragged, etc..  — Part of your question involves determining what you mean by "drag a file". An image displayed in a WebView can already be dragged. A link to a file can be dragged, but it'll still be just a link and not the file itself. (continued)

Comment: (continued) So, if you want to drag a link to a remote file out of a WebView and have the file itself appear at the destination, then you need to do something that'll intercept the link being dragged and replace it with the downloaded file.

Comment: I have no idea how Mail did it (wish someone could hack and tell). But I discovered how I could drag an image out of the WebView on to the desktop and change it into the desired file (only not on the position where your cursor was, but that's ok). Now I can display an image of an icon representing the file in the WebView in the app and let a user be able to drag the file out to the folder it wants. This way a user can easily drag a file in and out of the application, which was the nicest part in mail. Thanks for helping me with your thoughts. Topic closed.